# Does Application_OnStart in global.asax work with cached pages?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, global-asax

I'd like to implement a counter in global.asax so I can do a giveaway on my site every xxx visits. The question is, if my page is served from the ASP.NET cache, will the counter still update?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Application_OnStart` this event fires only once when you application started. To implement counter you should use `Session_Start` event. In this event increment counter.

Comment: Thomas, thanks for the correction. But the question still stands: will Session_Start fire when a page is being served from the cache?

Comment: @Shraga18: if you are using session_start event then your counter will increment when a new session will be created. So cache is not going to effect counter, only new session creation will increase it.

Comment: So a new session only gets started when the aspx page is requested? Is there any other event I could use which would work when a page is requested from cache?